# Setting properties of JavaScript objects created with Object.create()

Tags: javascript

Let's say there's a simple object created with the following JavaScript

```
 Builder = function (firstName, lastName) {
                this.firstName = firstName;
                this.lastName = lastName;
            }
            Builder.prototype.build = function () {
                return 'building....';
            };
            var b2 = new Builder('firstName', 'lastName');
```

I've been reading up on some of Douglas Crockford's work and he says that it's 'better'
to create objects like the following:

```
 var builder = {
                build: function () {
                    return 'building...';

                }, firstName: 'firstName'
                , lastName: 'lastName'
            };
            var b1 = Object.create(builder);
```

The Object.create() way is 'better' (and I would be curious to hear from an expert as to why), but I don't see how we could easily pass parameters to the second version for the values of 'firstName`and 'lastName`.  I'm much more familiar with C family syntax languages than JavaScript, but it seems to me that the constructor method of object creation is 'better'.  Why am I wrong? (Let's say for an enterprise-level environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Crockford's way, you would do the following:

`var build = function(firstName, lastName) {
    // do private stuff here.. but this closure will still be accessible to the returned object
    return {
      firstName:firstName,
      lastName:lastName
    }
  }`

var b = build('john', 'smith')

It's just as clean/powerfull as the OO way

Crockford's argument was that OO doesn't mix well with protypical inheritance.  He felt as though many of the OO constructs were added to the language and should have been thought out more clearly before doing so.  In my own code, I always try to follow his sound advice as he comes from the front lines  :)

Comment: The best way to see is by standing on the shoulders of giants :)

Comment: In my iteration builder was an object literal.  In your version it's a function.  What are the implications of this?

Comment: @wootscootingboogie, well for one, it can be leveraged with currying, partial application, etc.. Secondly, I find you can get by with less boiler plate with the latter technique

Answer (score 1):

You can pass initial values for `firstName` and `lastName` in the second argument to `Object.create()`:

```
var builder = {
    getFullName : function() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
};

var b1 = Object.create(builder, {
    firstName : { writable:true, configurable:true, value: "Joe" },
    lastName : { writable:true, configurable:true, value: "Shmoe" }
  }
);

b1.getFullName() //prints out: Joe Shmoe
```

Its very verbose, but you can create your own wrapper.

More details/examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Using_%3CpropertiesObject%3E_argument_with_Object.create).